# What Freshwater Fish Are Affected By Magnetic Fields

Tags: ichthyology

I am interested in knowing which freshwater fish are affected by magnetic fields.  I've heard that Lake Sturgeon are, but would like more references. This is for a project that will have buried 3 phase power cables.

Answer (score 1):

- [Sockeye salmon](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00657119) species [definitely](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00612020) do, although admittedly the [interesting salmon](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2614721/) are those that spend significant time in the ocean.
- Here's some evidence that [carp can](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3515494/).
- [Raindbow trout](http://www.pnas.org/content/early/2012/06/29/1205653109) are also [capable](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19669766).
- [Zebrafish](http://www.nature.com/srep/2012/121011/srep00727/full/srep00727.html) are [also able](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15753024).
- [Japanese eels](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15277551) too, of which some are freshwater.